# Is it possible to run a VM from a server into another motherboard and use the on-board GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, virtual-machine, cpu, motherboard, gpu

So let’s have a hypothetical set up: The computer uses an AMD server motherboard, running dual CPUs. Could you pipe the virtual machine data from the server into a workstations motherboard—say a micro ATX form factor—that has either no, or a really cheap processor, and then use the on-board GPU instead of the server’s GPU?

The essential idea is it possible to have a server taking the place of the processors of 8 computers. Then having those computers run with their own GPU?

Comment: Questions on hypothetical problems are extremely hard to answer.  Pipe the data from the server to what motherboard precisely?  There are ways to have a headless virtual machine appear on a local remote machine.  VMWare as numerous products that do that.

Comment: Unless you have an advanced degree in computer engineering, then no.  There isn't an "off the shelf" way to do this, unless you're only wanting to stream the VM to another machine.  Microsoft's RemoteFX is a reverse version of this - putting a hefty GPU on the Hyper-V server to feed underpowered remote clients.

Comment: This sounds like a thin client setup with local GPU processing, however hypervisors aren't set up to do this.  @GuitarPicker's suggestion of a massive server with multiple GPUs running dedicated in passthru mode may be doable.  However, the total cost of designing and implementing and licensing such a system will be more than if you just set up a bunch of gaming computers.  See: HP ProLiant WS400c Graphics Server Blades.  Keep in mind you need one per seat, and a thin client, per seat, and a rack and an enclosure and licenses.  So just build some gaming computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a common problem, except that the motivation is different.

Basically it amounts to running a Hypervisor with a VM on a *headless* server, then have a client displaying the graphical interface of the VM remotely. Let us assume you have configured your VM with a `Bridged Adapter` network interface, which will place the VM on the same LAN as the host (this can always be done).

What you wish can surely be done in VirtualBox, [read here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html). It can also be done in KVM, read [here](http://sophiedogg.com/creating-a-new-kvm-server-on-a-headless-machine/) how to setup a VM on a headless server (which means only using the CLI) and how to connect to it in a graphical session, [here](http://www.linuxnix.com/kvm-connect-to-a-virtual-machinessh-vnc-console-virt-viewer-etc/). And I have few doubts it can also be done in Xen, VMWare, HyperV, and so on. The choice is yours.

You must also keep in mind that, if you are considering using Unix machines, you can also run graphical applications on the headless server, and use the X11 of the remote client to display them. But this leaves Windows out, and also, for recent version of MacOS, you must install X11.